# What do you call this touch friendly scrolling select box?

Tags: terminology, select

[image]

[This proprietary select box](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/select#demo=basic) is an example of a UI element I'm wanting to add.

The essence of it is:

1. Only one item can be selected
2. It's designed for touch devices - you swipe upward to scroll down the list.

What do you call these style select boxes, for the purposes of googling?

Answer (score 14):

This type UI element is called **"Picker"**. Mostly used in iOS Mobile App. 
[CLICK HERE](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/pickers/) for more.

[image]

Comment: The 3D effect allows me to quickly see that it is scrollable. The image in the OP does not give me this insight.

Comment: Can we also suggest to the OP that the Picker is "considered harmful" and should not necessarily be used in his app without good reason.

Comment: @Coxy why is it? Apple use it themselves in many of their apps.

Comment: @Tim: One way the picker is annoying (as a user) is that it's often inconsistent. For example, this blood type picker is annoying because the options aren't sorted; I'm not sure if I should scroll up or down. Additionally, some pickers wrap around to the other end, while others don't. I'm not sure if I'd blacklist the entire concept of the picker as harmful, but every time I see one (as a user) I feel annoyed because it takes me a minute to figure out which way to scroll and whether things wrap. /rant

Comment: In Android, [pickers](https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-date-pickers) don't use that 3d effect and they can have Action buttons:   [image](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_10/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HVWZOVkdRQlJEdDg/components_pickers_date1.png)

Comment: Not everything Apple uses is good. Personally I don't like the picker. For example to select time, the new dialog in Android is much quicker than scrolling and selecting hour/min/sec separately

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I can clearly see that the list is scrollable with the selection line. And even if I don't know, touching the outside elements selects it immediately

Comment: I can't find the blog articles I was thinking of, but the IOS Picker is often considered to be quite a bad design, especially in its most common form as a date picker. Most third party calendar apps specifically build their own pickers due to user complaints. In the specific example shown of picking a blood type, there a number of problems with the native picker, first of which to me would that it ought to be trivial to fit all the main types without scrolling but the Picker makes that impossible.

Comment: If we talk about calendar picker, its not good option to choose during design. But for the drop downs, as a user I really like this picker, as it is more interactive then rest of the pickers I have used.